# Web design side decoration

Tags: photoshop

I was wondering if anyone know of some good tutorials on how to design and code side decorations(or whatever right term there is) like the ones on these website:

http://www.buckle.com/

I'm referring to the spring yellow and red flowers/butterflies

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty good place to start...

http://www.webdesignerwall.com/ (I have had a quick look through and ordered these more to less relevance)

- http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/how-to-css-large-background/
- http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/illustrator-abstract-vector-art/
- http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/design-process-of-the-phoenix/
- http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/photoshop-hand-drawn-design/
- http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/photo-strip-photoshop-tutorial/
- http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-decorative-gallery/
- http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/design-watercolor-effect-menu/

You might have flick through a couple of pages but it is really good and you will find plenty of other stuff too.

Comment: man this is some really good info. tnx a bunch for the links, I;m gonna take look at these tutorials tomorrow :)

Comment: Not a problem, if this answers your question feel free to accept the answer and/or vote the answer up... have a good one

Comment: done, thanks. So this technique is sort of called large background?

Comment: Ya would appear so... hope it helps you out.